# Adding Javascript to Branch.io deepviews in the HTML editor

Tags: branch.io

Is there a possibility to use Javascript in deepviews that will work on Safari? Initial testing did not run the script both inline and with src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackie from Branch here. 
Unfortunately, Javascript is not allowed in Deepviews. Before rendering the template, we sanitize the markup of Javascript for security reasons. This includes script tags and event attributes on tags. To learn more about customizing your Deepview template, please see our documentation [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/deep-views/#edit-deepview-templates).

Cheers,

Jackie

Comment: What would be your suggestion for implementing rich UI elements like image carousels?

Comment: You can write to `integrations@branch.io` and the team can enable usage of javascript for your deepview.